# How to use SSE2 & PREFETCHh instructions at the same time?

Tags: assembly, x86

In the Intel IA-32 architecture manual volume 3A chapter 2, the `CR4.OSFXSR` is explained as following:

> When set, enable the processor to execute SSE/SSE2/SSE3/SSSE3/SSE4 instructions, 
>   with the exception of the PAUSE,PREFETCHh, SFENCE, LFENCE, MFENCE,, MOVNTI, 
>   CLFLUSH, CRC32, and POPCNT.

The question is if I want to use SSE2 and PREFETCHh instructions at the same time, what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the wording could be clearer. What they meant to say is that `CR4.OSFXSR` bit only controls execution of instructions which work with SSE registers. The other instructions mentioned do not access SSE registers so they're always available (if implemented).

The following quote is a bit more clear:

> If this flag is clear, [...] Also, the processor will generate an invalid opcode exception (#UD) if
>   it attempts to execute any SSE/SSE2/SSE3 instruction, **with the
>   exception** of PAUSE, PREFETCHh, SFENCE, LFENCE, MFENCE, MOVNTI,
>   CLFLUSH, CRC32, and POPCNT.

Comment: why do someone want to disable the use of SSE?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

To Lưu Vĩnh Phúc:
Maybe disable it to save power consumption, as the related hardware logic is fully shutdown. Just a guess...

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: it's actually more about saving register context than about instructions themselves. To make sure that a program that uses SSE registers does not get its state corrupted if run under a non-SSE-aware OS.